# Detecting URL without http or www portion using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I know this question has been asked several times on this site but none could solve my problem. 
I want a regular expression to match a url ilke this 
bendlife.tumblr.com OR bendoeslife.com (both without http or www. portion)

this is my c# code

```
string pattern=@"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+.*)$"; //not working
///////@"^(?!www\\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\\/%&=\\?_:;-]+$"; not working either

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex urlRegEx=new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
bool matched=urlRegEx.IsMatch(description);
```

I will highly appreciate your help.
thanks.

Comment: what is your requirement , based on your requirement there might be multple ways to do the same , are you resolve url through httphandler??

Comment: @gov - I may not get your question but I want to say that this problem came up from xml feed that always stripped off "http://" of a url always leaving to just the domain part e.g. "stackoverflow.com" instead of "http://stackoverflow.com" so i need a regular expression to match this pattern and the subdomain like "test.stackoverflow.com". thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some sample inputs?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sane way to match a url fragment that doesn't start with a scheme, then I think you're stuck matching hostnames that have valid top-level domains. You can get [an authoritative list of all the TLDs from IADA](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/). Unfortunately, that's a long list, and too arbitrary to match programmatically, so you'll be stuck with a huge string in your regex unless you pare down the list some. But either way, search for a word that looks like `[^/]*\.(ac|ad|ae|aero|af|ag|…|zw)/.*` (word boundaries excepted).

Comment: thanks for the contribution but do mean "[^/]*\.(ac|ad|ae|aero|af|ag|…|zw)/.*" is all what i need? could provide me with the exact pattern to match the cases i cited? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first regex is that it ends in .*, thereby matching almost everything as long as it contains two dots. The second one can again end in almost everything.

Also, I think that most of the times, it's better to write a regex in parts, it's easier to see what you do, and change parts. For instance, you could try something like this:

```
extension = @"com|net|org";
dc = @"[-a-zA-Z0-9_]"; //always place the - at the start of the characters
dcnw = @"[-a-vxyzA-VXYZ0-9_]";
domainpart = dc + @"+"; 
firstdomainpart = @"(" + dcnw + dc + @"*)|(" + dc + dcnw + dc + @"*)|("
                +  dc + dc + dcnw + dc + @"*)|(" + dc + @"{4,})";
wholedomain = @"(" + firstdomainpart + @")+(\.("
            + domainpart + @"))*\.(" + extension + @")";
```

This way you're sure it will not begin with 'www' (at least i gathered that was your intention from the negative assertion in your regex). To exclude 'http://' add a backwards negative assertion at the start of the regex.

In my opinion the whole firstdomainpart is not very pretty, but I do not think you can solve it much better.

**edit:**
On second thought, i think the following should also work:

```
firstdomainpart = domainpart + @"(?!<www)";
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions.But please, could you help me with what has been tested and working? I'm confused by the code above. For instance, what is "domainchar" variable definition? also where should i place your second suggestion in the sample code? my interest is not to exclude http:// this has already been excluded in the source string leaving it to only to something like "test.stackoverflow.com" or "stackoverflow.com"

Comment: I'm sorry, i renamed domainchar to dc because i reused it a lot, but forget it in one place. All code is untested, it's also more to show you how to build a regex, instead of writing it in one big lump. eventually, `wholedomain` returns the regex you want to use.